# Current state of St Thomas and St John after hurricanes

Tags: weather-and-climate, event-based-effects, us-virgin-islands

It is now a few months since [a battery of devastating hurricanes hit the Caribbean islands](https://www.thenation.com/article/the-2017-hurricanes-didnt-just-hit-puerto-rico-they-hit-the-caribbean/). I'm planning on traveling to St. Thomas and St. John within the U.S. Virgin Islands for a few days in the month of February, as a tourist. I'm looking for specific information on the current and expected state of these islands after the impact of the hurricanes.

- Is it expected that many services will be unavailable (e.g., beaches/hiking/snorkeling)?
- Will travel around and between the islands (including the ferry) be difficult to come by?
- Is food/water safe?
- Are housing accommodations difficult to come by currently?
- Anything else I should know about the current state?

Any up-to-date information on these islands would be useful.

Update: This question got flagged as too broad but that is ridiculous. These are very specific questions. I cannot find any forums that have received responses from these islands. My guess is that the islands are in very bad shape and they are actively trying to keep information away from the public.

Could someone please clarify?

Comment: "Any up-to-date information on these islands would be useful": as would links to sites providing such information, which would probably be kept more current than a stack exchange answer.